# Golang Regular Expressions - what am I doing incorrectly?

Tags: regex, go

As a personal project, trying to learn Go(lang) by applying it to something, I am writing an EMCAScript/JavaScript "compiler"; all it will (initially) do is allow you to include other .js files.

Functionality aside, I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out the `regexp` package. Here is the snippet that does not seem to be doing what I want it to:

```
// Note: "lines" is an array of strings.

var includeRegex, _ = regexp.Compile("^[ \t]*include[(]{1}\"([^\"]+)\"[)]{1};")
for _, line := range lines {
   var isInclude = includeRegex.Match([]byte(line))
   if isInclude {
      var includeFile = includeRegex.FindString(line)
      fmt.Println("INCLUDE", includeFile)
   } else {
      // ...
   }
```

I have already stumbled across Go's subset of regular expressions, hence why the regex does not read as `^\s*include\("([^"]+)"\);`. I have already tested both the preferred, and the Go-style regex, in RegexPal, and both definitely work.  The match just never seems to occurr; what am I doing wrong?

For what it's worth, the `include()` statement I am trying to parse looks like so:

```
include("somefile.js");
```

EDIT: For what it's worth, I am keeping the code [here](https://github.com/indienick/jsc/).

Comment: I guess you have to escape the " once more when it is not in a character class. The one backslash you currently make is because it is in a string encapsulated with ".

Comment: So you mean I should change all instances of `\"` to `\\"`? I tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, and wrapping the "string" in backticks does not work, either.

Comment: For what it's worth, you might consider using the [new regexp package](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/regexp/) that's in the weekly builds now but will be part of Go version 1.

Comment: That's what I have been using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work with the latest weekly

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "regexp"
        "strings"
)

func main() {
        includeRegex, err := regexp.Compile(`^\s*include\("(\\\"|[^"])+"\);`)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        for _, line := range strings.Split(`
foo
include "abc.def"
include("file.js");
            include "me\"to\""
            include("please\"!\"");
        nothing here          
`, "\n") {
                if includeRegex.Match([]byte(line)) {
                        includeFile := includeRegex.FindString(line)
                        fmt.Println("INCLUDE", includeFile)
                } else {
                        fmt.Printf("no match for \"%s\"\n", line)
                }
        }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go build && ./tmp 
no match for ""
no match for "foo"
no match for "include "abc.def""
INCLUDE include("file.js");
no match for "        include "me\"to\"""
INCLUDE       include("please\"!\"");
no match for "  nothing here      "
no match for ""
$
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Updating to weekly seemed to make this work (despite me having to do a bit of a refactor to accommodate changes they have made since the `r60` release.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following line at the start of your program:

```
println(runtime.Version())
```

It should print `weekly.2012-03-13` or something close to that date.

Comment: It would appear I am running `release.r60.3 9516`. I am going to update to the weekly build and see how things go from there.

Comment: ... seems like my StackOverflow score is going to receive 15 points :)

Comment: Ugh - updating to the latest weekly, as opposed to running the last release, seems to break almost all of my code. *fffffffuuuuuuuuuuuu*